# Differences between 0x01 and 0x01f

Tags: java, floating-point, hex, int

I'm looking at the original source code for Identicons. 
There's a bit of code that does some bit twiddling to extract red, green and blue components:

```
int blue = (code >> 16) & 0x01f;
int green = (code >> 21) & 0x01f;
int red = (code >> 27) & 0x01f;
```

The code variable is a 32 bit integer.

My question is this: What's the difference between the number 0x01 and 0x01f?

I'm assuming the f means the value is a float, but why make it a float? Is it that the float representation in binary is different to the integer representation? Wouldn't that cause issues for portability reasons when porting if a particular language doesn't use the same representation?

Also, I'm probably reading this wrong on account of not understanding the 0x01f issue, but isn't this just setting the red, green and blue representations to either 0 or 1, depending on the least significant bit?

Comment: Of course, that was silly of me. My brain hasn't started up today apparently. 
So by this code, the RGB data would be a 16 bit 565 RGB value. 
But the green component of the colour only uses 5 of it's 6 bits. 
Does that mean that the Identicon code isn't using the total amount of the bits provided in the hash, ip etc.?

Comment: What are Identicons anyways? Some distant cousins of the Decepticons?

Comment: Identicons are the images that are assigned to your StackOverflow profile (like that pink and white identicon that my flair has up there). They're created based on a single integer to uniquely identify a user. 

So for instance, if I were posting anonymously and an image was attached to each post I made, no one could pretend that they were me (as they'd have a different IP and it would hash to a different image).You can use it for a lot of things, IP's, file hashes etc. It allows humans to quickly interpret if a given image matches a particular hash, without looking at a hex encoded number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That has nothing to do with floats. That's a bitmask.

```
0x01f = 0b11111
```

When you `&` your number with it, it clears all the bits to left of the 5th bit from the right.

Here's how `0x0a2bfb & 0x01f => 0x00001b`:

```
0x0a2bfb : 0000 1010 0010 1011 1111 1011
0x01f    : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 &
----------------------------------------
result   : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1011
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Java, but in C99, hex floats [really do exist](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hex-Floats.html), and they look like this:

```
0x50.1p3
```

The `p` suffix is mandatory (and is used to indicate the power of 2 to raise the number).  Hence, there is no ambiguity with hex integer literals like `0x01f`.  The compiler won't mistake `f` for a floating point constant suffix, it'll read it as a hex digit.

Comment: That also works in Java (to my surprise - learned something new!), 0x50.1p3 is equal to 640.5.

Answer (score 2):

`f` in the context of hexadecimal is *not* a float. `0xf` is equivalent to decimal `15`.

In your example, the code is finding the least significant 5 bits of the color code, likely in a 15 or 16bit color space