# Why does this code print 16 in java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, ascii

Can someone explain the underlying mechanics behind this chunk of code.

```
System.out.println(0x10);
```

Comment: 0x10 is hex form of 16

Comment: Did you expect it to print something different?

Comment: @AhmedAbdulkareem **0x** represents Hex, **0b** represents Binary and **0** before a number represents Octal - therefore, what you have here is hexadecimal 10 which is 16 in decimal and Java outputs the answer in decimal format :-)

Comment: See also: [What does "0xFF00" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24211736)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0x` indicates the compiler that the following literals are supposed to be a hex number witch in your example is 10 hex or 16 decimal

Answer (score 0):

0x or 0X in front of the numbers are hex format.

Why 16:

```
0x1          0

  1 * 16^1 + 0 * 16^0
= 1 * 16   + 0 * 1 
= 16       + 0 
= 16
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hex number and in decimal it is 16